# How to fix the model to correctly use the MVC Foolproof library?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, foolproof-validation

I am trying to use MVC Foolproof library to validate my model and show error message respectively. However I am not applying the Data Annotation correctly so the validation does not works.

My requirement is that I have two checkboxes and atleast one of them needs to be checked before submitting the form. Below is the code for both fields in the model with data annotation,

```
    [RequiredIfFalse("CheckBox2", ErrorMessage = "Please select atleast one checkbox.")]
    public bool Checkbox1 { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfFalse("Checkbox1", ErrorMessage = "Please select atleast one checkbox.")]
    public bool CheckBox2 { get; set; }
```

Now when I submit the form without checking any checkbox then form is submitted and no error is displayed. I know there is some logical mistake with the model and the way I am applying the custom validation attribute because if I make first field as int or string and make it required if the CheckBox is checked then validation works fine and validation messages are displayed accordingly on the view. Kindly help me in identifying the logical error in above fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my problem is solved when I modified the Foolproof's Data Annotations as below,

```
    [RequiredIfNot("CheckBox2", true, ErrorMessage = "Please select atleast one checkbox.")]
    public bool CheckBox1 { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfNot("CheckBox1", true, ErrorMessage = "Please select atleast one checkbox.")]
    public bool CheckBox2 { get; set; }
```

Through this I am actually checking the value which was not achieved by using RequiredIfFalse which was used to check if value is provided or not and I thought that it is checking that whether field value is false. Thanks to @Stephen Muecke for clarifying it to me.

The only short coming is that when both checkboxes are not checked then the error message is displayed for both controls which I want to be displayed just once. But when any of the checkbox is checked then validation works just fine and no error messages are displayed.

Edit: The duplicate error message is removed if I use ErrorMessage=" " for any of the CheckBox. So the error message will be displayed once if no CheckBox is checked and if any of the CheckBox is checked then no error messages will be displayed.

Edit:
Here is the code for view,

```
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckBox1)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CheckBox1)
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckBox2)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CheckBox2)
            </div>
```

The code for model is also given and now I have provided the code for view. Nothing else being done on the controller and it works without a hack. The error is being displayed in the Validation Summary automatically. I have also used ValidationFor and it works fine with that too.

Comment: Not really sure how your claiming this works (it does not). A `[RequiredIfNot]` (which derives from `[RequiredIf]` means that the property it is applied to must have a value (i.e. not `null` or not an empty `string`) based on the value of the other property. Since a bool value is always either `true` or `false` (can never be `null` or an empty `string`) validation **always** passes. You can see the source code for the `IsValid()` method [here](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Foolproof/RequiredIf.cs)

Comment: I can only assume you are not using `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` or your doing some hack in the view to make this work

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I am using @Html.CheckBoxFor() and haven't using any other hacks.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke You have to try atleast once to see how this works. You were right earlier but not this time. You are seeing RequiredIfNot as alone but see the parameters. If you will see the parameters then you will know that it is doing comparison with value. I don't understand why you don't think this works and why you are insisting but it works absolutely fine for me. I will insist that give it a try to get out of denial state.

Comment: I have tried it (including downloading the source code and stepping through it). And if I was right earlier then I am right again because `[RequiredIfFalse("CheckBox2")]` is the same a `[RequiredIfNot("CheckBox2", true]` - look at the source code - the first is just a short cut for the second (they all derive from `[RequiredIf]` - the first just automatically generates the second parameter so you don't need to pass it).

Comment: I can't comment on your view because you have not posted it, but I suggest you disable client side validation (or just comment out `"~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.js")" `) and then test it by leaving both checkboxes unchecked. An error will NOT be added to `ModelState`. Look at this line of the source code I linked to - `return value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString().Trim());` Since `value` will be either `true` or `false`, the method returns `true` (indicating its valid). It can never be `null` or and empty `string` unless you have done something unusual in the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke check the answer below

Comment: @StephenMuecke You mean creating a duplicate question? Why

Comment: I was questioning why you added that now deleted comment - its was not clear if you were asking a question or trying to answer :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Deleted it because it lacked clarity as a comment. Purpose was to illustrate what the OP meant because I'm facing same problems and find your observations quite confusing.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Required]
public bool DidWin {get;set;}

[RequiredIfFalse(nameof(DidWin))]
public string ExplainationWhyDidntWin {get;set;}  // Doesn't work

[RequiredIfNot(nameof(DidWin), true)]
public string ExplainationWhyDidntWin2 {get;set;} // Works
```

In order to fix the issue, find `mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.js` and replace the following:

```
var isBool = function (input) {
    return input === true || input === false || input === "true" || input === "false";
};
```

with

```
var isBool = function (input) {
    return input === true || input === false || input.toLowerCase() === "true" || input.toLowerCase() === "false";
};
```

and

```
else if (isBool(value1)) {
    if (value1 == "false") value1 = false;
    if (value2 == "false") value2 = false;
    value1 = !!value1;
    value2 = !!value2;
}
```

with

```
else if (isBool(value1) && isBool(value2)) {
    if (value1 == "false") value1 = false;
    if (value2.toLowerCase() == "false") value2 = false;
    value1 = !!value1;
    value2 = !!value2;
}
```

Comment: This is a completely different scenario to the question (which is 2 properties which are typeof `bool`) and therefore is not an answer to the question (and making these changes would do nothing to solve OP's problem)

Answer (score 1):

A boolean has only 2 states (`true` or `false`) and either one is valid so `[RequiredIfFalse]` is effectively saying that the value must be either `true` or `false`, which it always will be assuming your using `@Html.CheckBoxFor()`. You cannot use a Foolproof  validation attribute for this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There must be some way to validate this using Foolproof. Some workaround?

Comment: No there is not. 'Required' means its required (not null) and a `boolean` is never null. Easiest workaround is just to check the values in the POST method and if both are `false`, add a model state error - `ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please check Checkbox1 and/or Checkbox2");`, and it will be displayed in the `@Html.ValidationSummary()`

Comment: Forgive me but it feel strange. If a CheckBox is not checked then its value is false and if it is checked then its value is true. So RequiredIfFalse should mean that to show message if CheckBox is not checked. What you are saying is that RequiredIfFalse don't work because it is not null. I am talking about RequiredIfFalse and not just required

Comment: Your clearly not understanding the logic. `[RequiredIfFalse("CheckBox2")]` applied to property `CheckBox1` means that the value of `CheckBox1` is required if the value of `CheckBox2` is false. Which means if `CheckBox2` is `false` then `CheckBox1` must have a value - which it **always** will because both `true` and `false` are values! (a `boolean` cannot have a `null` value`)

Comment: Thank you. I was mistaken because I thought RequiredIfFalse is checking the false value of checkbox which it is clearly not. But clearly you were also not right that this has no other solution. I played around with other Attributes and found that [RequiredIfNot("CheckBox1", true) fulfill my requirements. The only short coming is that when both CheckBoxes are not checked it display error message for both CheckBox but when atleast one CheckBox is checked then there is no error. I will post this as answer if other needs it and thank you for clarifying logic to me.

Comment: If you really want a validation attribute to do this correctly, then write your own - [refer this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: Sure I will use custom attribute but I have also fixed the duplicate message by setting ErrorMessage=" " for one CheckBox. So this one now works just fine.